# How do I highlight text in PHP with conditions?

Tags: php

I have some numbers, and depending on the number's value I need to highlight a string which is in a table. The table is not in database.

Does anyone know how to highlight text in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP won't "highlight" text, that is done with CSS/HTML. You only use PHP to output the correct HTML.

Something like this:

```
$my_num = 9;
foreach ($my_array_of_numbers as $num)
{
   // See if $num matches $my_num, if so - add the "highlight"
   // class to the HTML element we're using
   $css_class = ($num == $my_num) ? 'highlight' : '';
   echo '<td class="'.$css_class.'">'.$num.'</td>';
}
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background:yellow;
}
```

You may also want to consider using javascript for this, which can handle the task after the HTML has already been generated.

Answer (score 1):

Presentation, like highlighting, is done in CSS, not PHP.

My advice would be to create a CSS class which has a background-color defined to be used as highlighting. Then, in PHP, you can conditionally wrap your string in `<span>` tags which have that class, so the text would be highlighted.

CSS:

```
.highlight {
   background-color: #FF0;
}
```

PHP:

```
if (highlightCondition) {
   echo '<span class="highlight">' . $string . '</span>';
} else {
   echo $string;
}
```